# SQL Find the minimum date based on consecutive values

Tags: sql, run-length-encoding

I'm having trouble constructing a query that can find consecutive values meeting a condition. Example data below, note that Date is sorted DESC and is grouped by ID.

[image]

To be selected, for each ID, the most recent RESULT must be 'Fail', and what I need back is the earliest date in that run of 'Fails'.  For ID==1, only the 1st two values are of interest (the last doesn't count due to prior 'Complete'.  ID==2 doesn't count at all, failing the first condition, and for ID==3, only the first value matters.

A result table might be:

[image]

The trick seems to be doing some type of run-length encoding, but even with several attempts manipulating ROW_NUM and an attempt at the tabibitosan method for grouping consecutive values, I've been unable to gain traction.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your database?Tag appropriately

Comment: And please share an example of what you've already tried.

Answer (score 2):

If your database supports window functions, you can do

```
select id, case when result='Fail' then earliest_fail_date end  earliest_fail_date
    from (
    select t.*
    ,row_number() over(partition by id order by dt desc) rn
    ,min(case when result = 'Fail' then dt end) over(partition by id) earliest_fail_date
    from tablename t
    ) x 
where rn=1
```

Use `row_number` to get the latest row in the table. `min() over()` to get the earliest fail date for each id. If the first row has status Fail, you select the earliest_fail_date or else it would be null.

It should be noted that the expected result for id=1 is wrong. It should be 2016-09-20 as it is the earliest fail date.

Edit: Having re-read the question, i think this is what you might be looking for. Getting the minimum Fail date from the latest consecutive groups of Fail rows.

```
with grps as (
select t.*,row_number() over(partition by id order by dt desc) rn
,row_number() over(partition by id order by dt)-row_number() over(partition by id,result order by dt) grp
from tablename t
) 
,maxfailgrp as (
select g.*,
max(case when result = 'Fail' then grp end) over(partition by id) maxgrp 
from grps g
)
select id,
case when result = 'Fail' then (select min(dt) from maxfailgrp where id = m.id and grp=m.maxgrp) end earliest_fail_date
from maxfailgrp m
where rn=1
```

[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/ITJTM30096)